# SQL response is treated as column name, rather than content in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, exception

Method below gets result set from SQL database and populates a `Map<String,String>`. It works well in most cases, but with this particular query I get an exception saying:

> Unable to execute query: `select RULEID, GRAPHRULE from GRAPHRULE3D WHERE GRAPHRULE LIKE '%1717-002%' AND GRAPHRULE NOT LIKE '%DRAWING%'`
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name ('1717-002'); is not valid.

Query itself works on SQL Server. Why does it think that `('1717-002');` in second column is a column name, while it is actually a value?

---

Problem follows `String value = rs.getString(rs.getString(2).trim());` if I drop it I get a set of `String key =Integer.toString((Integer) rs.getObject(1));` without a problem.

```
//String query = "select RULEID, GRAPHRULE from GRAPHRULE3D WHERE GRAPHRULE LIKE '%1717-002%' AND GRAPHRULE NOT LIKE '%DRAWING%'"
public Map<String,String> getStrinfStringPairsFromIntegerStringSQL(String query) {

    return processContent(query, (rs) -> {
        Map<String,String> optionDescriptions = new TreeMap<>();

        while (rs.next()) {

            String key =Integer.toString((Integer) rs.getObject(1));
            String value = rs.getString(rs.getString(2).trim());

            optionDescriptions.put(key, value);
        }
        return optionDescriptions;
    });
}


@FunctionalInterface
public static interface ResultSetHandler<S, T> {

    Map<S, T> accept(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException;
}

public <S, T> Map<S, T> processContent(String query, ResultSetHandler handler) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
            try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
                try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
                    return handler.accept(resultSet);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to execute query: " + query, e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EngineSQLUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Wait... you're taking a value from the resultset and use it as a column name in that same resultset? That can't possibly work... If your resultset has `1717-002` as a value, that line `rs.getString(rs.getString(2).trim());` will expand to `rs.getString("1717-002");`. Surely you didn't mean something like that? You have two columns `RULEID, GRAPHRULE`...

Comment: I am using `String value = rs.getString(rs.getString(2).trim());` - trying to get a string in second column (say it has `foo`).  Instead Java believes that I am trying to search for a column with a name `foo`.

Comment: Oh, got it. my copy-paste error. thank you. Make it an answer please, so I can close the question.

Comment: Java is right... the method `ResultSet.getString( string columnName )` will look up the value for the `columnName` passed to it. You are passing a value for column `GRAPHRULE` that being `1717-002` and use that to look up a value for column `1717-002`. There is no column `1717-002` in your resultset!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're taking a value from the resultset and use it as a column name in that same resultset. That will not work with the query you have.

If your resultset has `1717-002` as a value, that line `rs.getString(rs.getString(2).trim());` will expand to `rs.getString("1717-002");`. Surely you didn't mean something like that? You only have columns `RULEID` and `GRAPHRULE`.

Answer (score 1):

`RULE` is a reserved word in SQL-server, so your query is wrong.
If you can, I recommend to change the column name, just a source of problems.
If you can't, try `WHERE RULESET.RULE  LIKE '%1717-002%'` or `WHERE [RULE] LIKE '%1717-002%'`

Comment: Sorry, I made up the names. It was actually `RULEID, GRAPHRULE  from GRAPHRULE3D ...`. Also, it works in SQL server app.